# How to set innertext of class

Tags: c#, html, htmlcollection

I got this code in my webpage:

```
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption">
      TestText
</div>
```

I was wondering how I can access this class and change `TestText` into some other string using C#.

I was trying with `HtmlCollection`, but there's no InnerText option.

**EDIT: I CANT CHANGE CODE ABOVE.**

Comment: update question with what you tried with HtmlCollection

Comment: is it urgent to take class not id and use runat="server" inside div tag..

Comment: does the div appear in a parent control with a runat=server tag?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using `ASP.NET` and your div is inside atleast one container having runat="server" attribute i.e. Form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption">
        TestText
    </div>
</form>
```

you can simply do this:

```
var xml = form1.InnerHtml;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var nodes = doc.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class,'goog-inline-block goog')]");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   node.InnerText = " changed Text";
}
form1.InnerHtml = xml = doc.InnerXml;
```

using **Linq to SQL** i.e **XDocument**

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var nodes = doc.Elements("div")
               .Where(s => s.Attribute("class").Value
                            .Contains("goog-inline-block goog")
                     )
               .ToList();
foreach (XElement elem in nodes)
{
   elem.Value = "changed text";
}
form1.InnerHtml = doc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the **runat="server"** and **id** attribute to it so you have:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" runat="server" >
      TestText
</div>
```

you can use the class attribute by using:

> mydiv.Attributes["class"] = "classOfYourChoice";

or

> mydiv.InnerText = "Your Selected text";

Hope you understand and helps for you..

Comment: you would have to use .contains to check if the class contains the class of your choice

Answer (score 0):

In C# you need to give id and set runat="server" in div tag like this.

```
<div id="divTest" runat="server" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption">
      TestText
</div>
```

then
In C# Code behind

```
divText.InnerText = "Change Text From Here.";
```

try this, if not work then please explain me your question in detail.